# Getting Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to dynamically change the style of an element `.item` in my page but I am getting error

```
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')
```

Here is my Style

```
.item {
    flex: 0 0 calc(12% - 20px);
    background: #36bf00;
    color: white;
    margin: 10px 10px -20px 10px;
}
```

And this is my html code

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
    <script>
        var folder = "images/";

        $.ajax({
            url : folder,
            success: function (data) {
                $(data).find("a").attr("href", function (i, val) {
                    if( val.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/) ) { 
                        $("#container").append( "<div class='item'><img src='"+ folder + val +"'></div>" );
                    } 
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
    </div>

    <script>
    $(document).keydown(function(e){
        var imgsize = 12;
        var ItemClass = document.getElementById("item");

        if (e.keyCode == 38) { // Up
            console.log("up")
            var NewImgsize = imgsize + 0.5;
            var NewStyle = '0 0 calc(' + NewImgsize + '% - 20px';
            document.getElementById('item').style.flex = NewStyle;
            return false;
        }
        if (e.keyCode == 40) { //Down
            console.log("down")
            imgsize = imgsize + 0.5;
            return false;
        }
    })
    </script>

</body>
```

Any idea what I am missing?

Thanks

Comment: you are accessing the element the wrong way.
document.getElementById('item') is accessing by id "item" ... do you have one?

Comment: you need to make sure that the element with the id item exists before you try to change its style. You can do this by using the `querySelector()  const itemElement = document.querySelector('#item');`

Comment: @AlonMalivanchuk, I have updated the code to include the whole page. The 'item' is being generated dynamically but it will be displayed already before the request to change the style is requested by arrow key up.

Comment: Why are you using native DOM methods when you're using jQuery? You should really pick one or the other for consistency.

Comment: You're adding an element with class 'item' not id, then trying to access it by getElementById. You need to set the items id attribute or get it via its class name instead.

Comment: Can you post the html loaded in the browser?

Answer (score 1):

try this instead

```
document.getElementsByClassName('item');
```

It will get elements by className.

Comment: pay attention that you are getting an array of elements by accessing element by class name so probably the code will be like:
`var ItemClass = document.getElementsByClassName('item')[0];`